# formatter.js overrides knockout value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js for binding values to view.
When modal is shown i initialize formatter. Here is sample:

```
<input type="text" id="propertyName" class="form-control" name="name" required="" data-bind="value: Name">

$("#exampleFormModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        self.InitFormatter();
    });

    self.InitFormatter = function () {
        $('#propertyName').formatter({
           'pattern': '{{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}',
           'persistent': true
        });
    }
```

The problem is that there is empty values in `value: Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using knockout with a library that does any kind of DOM manipulation - including value updates on elements - requires a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), so that knockout can a) initialize that library properly and b) pass any updates between viewmodel and view.

Writing a custom binding handler for formatter.js is tricky, because formatter.js takes very tight control of all value-related events (keyboard, paste) that happen on an input element - without exposing any events of its own.

In other words, it's easy to set up, but it's hard to be notified when a value changes. But that is exactly what's necessary to keep the viewmodel up-to-date.

To be able to do it anyway, we must hook into one of the internal functions of formatter - the [`_processKey` method](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js/blob/master/dist/formatter.js#L633). This method is called whenever the value of an input changes, so it's the perfect spot to set up a little "snitch" that tells knockout when the value changes.

**Disclaimer** This is a hack. It will break whenever the formatter.js internals change. With the current version 0.1.5 however, it seems to work rather well.

This way we can bind our view like this:

```html
<input data-bind="formatter: {
    value: someObservable,
    pattern: '{{9999}}-{{9999}},
    persistent: true
}">
```

and knockout can fill in the input value whenever `someObservable` changes, and thanks to the hook into `_processKey` it also can update `someObservable` whenever the input value changes.

The full implementation of the binding handler follows (it has no jQuery dependency):

```
// ko-formatter.js
/* global ko, Formatter */

ko.bindingHandlers.formatter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {},
            instance = new Formatter(element, ko.toJS(options)),
            _processKey = Formatter.prototype._processKey,
            valueSubs, patternSubs, patternsSubs;

        if (ko.isWritableObservable(options.value)) {
            // capture initial element value
            options.value(element.value);
            // shadow the internal _processKey method so we see value changes
            instance._processKey = function () {
                _processKey.apply(this, arguments);
                options.value(element.value);
            };
            // catch the 'cut' event that formatter.js originally ignores
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'input', function () {
                options.value(element.value);
            });
            // subscribe to options.value to achieve two-way binding
            valueSubs = options.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                // back out if observable and element values are equal
                if (newValue === element.value) return;
                // otherwise reset element and "type in" new observable value
                element.value = '';
                _processKey.call(instance, newValue, false, true);
                // write formatted value back into observable
                if (element.value !== newValue) options.value(element.value);
            });
        }
        // support updating "pattern" option through knockout
        if (ko.isObservable(options.pattern)) {
            patternSubs = options.pattern.subscribe(function (newPattern) {
                instance.resetPattern(newPattern);
            });
        }
        // support updating "patterns" option through knockout
        if (ko.isObservable(options.patterns)) {
            patternsSubs = options.patterns.subscribe(function (newPatterns) {
                instance.opts.patterns = newPatterns;
                instance.resetPattern();
            });
        }
        // clean up after ourselves
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            if (valueSubs) valueSubs.dispose();
            if (patternSubs) patternSubs.dispose();
            if (patternsSubs) patternsSubs.dispose();
        });
    }
    // this binding has no "update" part, it's not necessary
};
```

This also supports making the `pattern` observable, so you can change the pattern for an input field dynamically.

Live demo (expand to run):

```js
// ko-formatter.js
/* global ko, Formatter */

ko.bindingHandlers.formatter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {},
            instance = new Formatter(element, ko.toJS(options)),
            _processKey = Formatter.prototype._processKey,
            valueSubs, patternSubs, patternsSubs;

        if (ko.isWritableObservable(options.value)) {
            // capture initial element value
            options.value(element.value);
            // shadow the internal _processKey method so we see value changes
            instance._processKey = function () {
                _processKey.apply(this, arguments);
                options.value(element.value);
            };
            // catch the 'cut' event that formatter.js originally ignores
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'input', function () {
                options.value(element.value);
            });
            // subscribe to options.value to achieve two-way binding
            valueSubs = options.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                // back out if observable and element values are equal
                if (newValue === element.value) return;
                // otherwise reset element and "type" new observable value
                element.value = '';
                _processKey.call(instance, newValue, false, true);
                // write formatted value back into observable
                if (element.value !== newValue) options.value(element.value);
            });
        }
        // support updating "pattern" option through knockout
        if (ko.isObservable(options.pattern)) {
            patternSubs = options.pattern.subscribe(function (newPattern) {
                instance.resetPattern(newPattern);
            });
        }
        // support updating "patterns" option through knockout
        if (ko.isObservable(options.patterns)) {
            patternsSubs = options.patterns.subscribe(function (newPatterns) {
                instance.opts.patterns = newPatterns;
                instance.resetPattern();
            });
        }
        // clean up after ourselves
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            if (valueSubs) valueSubs.dispose();
            if (patternSubs) patternSubs.dispose();
            if (patternsSubs) patternsSubs.dispose();
        });
    }
    // this binding has no "update" part, it's not necessary
};

// viewmodel implementation

ko.applyBindings({
    inputPattern: ko.observable('{{9999}}-{{9999}}-{{9999}}-{{9999}}'),
    inputValue: ko.observable(),
    setValidValue: function () {
        var dummy = this.inputPattern().replace(/\{\{([a9*]+)\}\}/g, function ($0, $1) {
            return $1.replace(/\*/g, "x");
        });
        this.inputValue(dummy);
    },
    setInvalidValue: function () {
        this.inputValue('invalid value');
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formatter.js/0.1.5/formatter.min.js"></script>

View:<br>
<input data-bind="formatter: {
    value: inputValue,
    pattern: inputPattern,
    persistent: true
}">
<input data-bind="value: inputPattern"><br>
<button data-bind="click: setValidValue">Set valid value</button>
<button data-bind="click: setInvalidValue">Set invalid value</button>

<hr>
Viewmodel:<br>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null ,2)"></pre>
```